# TypeScript: Dynamicaly change returned object properties to required

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a function that returns this:

```js
interface result {
  A?: string;
  B?: string;
  C?: string;
}
```

Using an array parameter of a function, How can I make some of my return parameter not-null and required? Something like this:

```js
function toRequired(keysToTurnRequired: string[]): CorrectResult {
}
```

If i run for example `toRequired(['A', 'B'])` then my return type should be this:

```
result {
  A!: string;
  B!: string;
  C?: string;
}
```

Is there any generic way to achieve this in Typescript? It is super useful to achieve type safety when joining relations form ORM repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the types ahead of time, and then use type narrowing; but you can't really create the types during runtime, because Typescript exists more for your dev environment, and at runtime the code has already been transpiled into Javascript.

```
interface ResultBase {
    A?: string;
    B?: string;
    C?: string;
  } 
  
  interface ResultAB extends Partial<ResultBase> {
    A: string;
    B: string;
  }

  const isResultAB = (candidate: ResultBase): candidate is ResultAB => {
      return ('A' in candidate && typeof 'A' === 'string') &&
         ('B' in candidate && typeof 'B' === 'string')
  }

  const x = {
      A: 'sfsdf',
      B: 'bbbb'
  }

  if (isResultAB) {
      // Now we know we have a type ResultAB
  }
```